# Graph to show departure and arrival times between stations

Tags: vba, matlab, excel, graph, nodes

I have the start and end times of trips made by a bus, with the times in an Excel sheet. I want to make the graph as below :

[image: Figure]

I tried with Matlab nodes and graphs but did not got the exact figure, below is the Matlab code which I tried as an example:

```
A = [1 4] 
B = [2 3]
weights = [5 5];
G = digraph(A,B,weights,4)
plot(G)
```

And the figure it generates:

[image: fig]

I have got many more than 4 points in the Excel sheet, and I want them to all be displayed as in the first image.

Comment: Do you want to create the graph in matlab or excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Overview

You don't need any sort of complicated graph package for this, just use normal line plots! Here are methods in Excel and Matlab.

### Excel

Give each bus stop a number, and list the bus stop number by the time it arrives/leaves there. I'll use stops number 0 and 1 for this example.

```
0   04:41
1   05:35
1   05:40
0   06:34
0   06:51
1   07:45
1   15:21
0   16:15
```

Then simply highlight the data and insert a "scatter with straight lines"

[image: scatter]

The rest is formatting. You can format the y-axis and tick "values in reverse order" to get the time increasing as in your desired plot. You can change the x-axis tick marks to just show integer stop numbers, get rid of the legend etc.

Final output:

[image: Excel output]

---

### Matlab

Here is the Matlab documentation for converting Excel formatted dates into Matlab `datetime` arrays: [Convert Excel Date Number to Datetime](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#buhzxor-5).

Once you have the `datetime` objects, you can do this easily with the standard `plot` function.

```matlab
% Set times up as a datetime array, could do this any number of ways
times = datetime(strcat({'1/1/2000 '}, {'04:41', '05:35', '05:40', '06:34', '06:51', '07:45', '15:21', '16:15'}, ':00'), 'format', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
% Set up the location of the bus at each of the above times
station = [0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0];
% Plot
plot(station, times)              % Create plot
set(gca, 'xtick', [0,1])          % Limit to just ticks at the 2 stops
set(gca, 'ydir', 'reverse')       % Reverse y axis to have earlier at top
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'R', 'L'})  % Name the stops
```

Output:

[image: bus routes]

Comment: Thanks!! Converting the number from excel into matlab does not give the exact time, there is a change of few minutes. I am not concerned about the date however. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: You would have to give me an example, or I can only refer you back to the documentation...

Comment: Beautiful -- thank you so much! Saved me a lot of time in excel.